# How do I assign a specific color to a specific line? (google.visualization)

Tags: google-visualization

How do I set the color of a specific line(s) on a line chart, using google charts (google.visualization API)? I'm visualizing a data set that already has specific colors associated with each line (and the color associations are important).

I know about setting a general palette via the chart options, e.g.:

```
chart.draw(dataTable, { colors: ['red', '#ff9933', 'pink', /* ...etc... */ ] });
```

But I don't want to set a palette, I want to assign specific colors to specific lines.  Ideally, I'd like to put the colors in the data table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the colors in the DataTable, but you can assign them by data series, using the series option:

```
chart.draw(dataTable, {
    series: {
        0: {
            // set the color of the first data series
            color: 'red'
        },
        1: {
            // set the color of the second data series
            color: '#ff9933'
        },
        2: {
            // set the color of the third data series
            color: 'pink'
        }
        // etc
    }
});
```

If your data series are dynamic, you can build the colors dynamically as well, and set them in the options at draw time.